# Make gazebo subscribe to a ROS topic?

Tags: ros, gazebo, msg-subscriber, topic, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've noticed that there are some ros topics that have the gazebo as a subscriber. Can someone tell me how can I make gazebo subscribe to a topic I create or where I can learn about it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280088/make-gazebo-subscribe-to-a-ros-topic?/) by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For this you have to write Gazebo plugin which is basically C++ code interacting with Gazebo environment.

Have a look at tutorial official tutorial [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=plugins_hello_world).

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1